# How to generate list of vectors within a sphere?

Tags: c#, loops, vector

I'm trying to generate mining points within an asteroid for a game.
With that said, I have the asteroid center point, the radius of the asteroid, and the size of the ship I'm using.

Here is my method, but it's creating vectors outside of the range of the asteroid.

```
private void ExpandAreaOfControl()
{
    int yStart = (int)TargetLocation.Y;
    int xStart = (int)TargetLocation.X;
    int zStart = (int)TargetLocation.Z;

    int startGridSize = 20;
    for (double y = startGridSize; y < Size / 2; y += startGridSize)
    {
        for (double x = startGridSize; x < Size / 2; x += startGridSize)
        {
            for (double z = startGridSize; z < Size / 2; z += startGridSize)
            {
                var point1 = new MineralPoint(new Vector3D(xStart + x, yStart + y, zStart + z));
                mineralDeposits.Add(point1);

                var point2 = new MineralPoint(new Vector3D(xStart + x, yStart + y, zStart - z));
                mineralDeposits.Add(point2);

                var point3 = new MineralPoint(new Vector3D(xStart + x, yStart - y, zStart - z));
                mineralDeposits.Add(point3);

                var point4 = new MineralPoint(new Vector3D(xStart + x, yStart - y, zStart + z));
                mineralDeposits.Add(point4);

                var point5 = new MineralPoint(new Vector3D(xStart - x, yStart + y, zStart + z));
                mineralDeposits.Add(point5);

                var point6 = new MineralPoint(new Vector3D(xStart - x, yStart - y, zStart + z));
                mineralDeposits.Add(point6);

                var point7 = new MineralPoint(new Vector3D(xStart - x, yStart + y, zStart - z));
                mineralDeposits.Add(point7);

                var point8 = new MineralPoint(new Vector3D(xStart - x, yStart - y, zStart - z));
                mineralDeposits.Add(point8);
            }
        }
    }
    mineralDeposits = mineralDeposits.OrderBy(y => (y.Location - StartPosition).Length()).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do, if you want to keep you current code, is to get the vector that goes from the center of the asteroid to the mineral you've just created.

After obtaining that vector, divide it by its length, and multiply it by the radius of the asteroid - this will put the point right on its surface, but at the same angle it was at previously.

If you want the mineral to be inside the asteroid instead then multiply the vector by a number smaller than the radius.

*If you want another technique - create a 3d vector with random values (make sure they're not all 0), and do the same as previously explained (starting from the 2nd paragraph).*

Finally, after obtaining the result of your multiplied vector, add the asteroid's center position vector to it and you have your mineral position (relative to the coord origin used by the asteroid).